# ColorPrimaryDark theme android doesnt display in all Activities in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-design, android-appcompat

I hope you can help me.
I created my style.xml in values-v21, so I put the theme for the entire application, but the colorPrimaryDark only works in the main activity and other activities not working.

```css
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
....
....
</application>
```

```html
values-v21/styles.xml

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```